# Is posible to scrollToElement() with Swift when UI Testing in Xcode 7.0.1?

Tags: ios, swift, testing, xcode7, xcode-ui-testing

I just started doing some UI Testing with Swift in Xcode 7 (7.0.1) and have one think to resolve in order to continue testing.

My app have a Table View with a lot of cells, and I want to Tap in one cell that is not visible; at this moment the workarround I have is to SwipeUp() and then tap at the cell when is visible.

It works, but is not efficient, because there is a chance that when I SwipeUP() the cell I want to Tap won't be visible, for Swiping to much, and can't Tap at the cell.

I need to Scroll instead of swipe.

If anyone have links of resources about Swift for UI Testing so I can continue reading I'll be really grateful.

Cheers,
Chino.

Answer (score 4):

Update:
Apple has added scroll function to XCUIElement that takes number of pixels to scroll. This might work better than the below suggestion. I have not yet tried the new scroll function from Apple. 
https://developer.apple.com/reference/xctest/xcuielement/1500758-scroll

This is a real issue that Apple has to address. Till then a workaround is to use

```
let element = <Any XCUIElement>
let topPoint = element.coordinateWithNormalizedOffset(CGVectorMake(0.5, 0.25))
let bottomPoint =  element.coordinateWithNormalizedOffset(CGVectorMake(0.5, 0.75))
bottomPoint.pressForDuration(0.1, thenDragToCoordinate: topPoint)
```

We can have finer control over scroll compared to swipe functions using this snippet.

If you consider using it, I suggest you to add this snippet as extension to XCUIElement.

Answer (score 0):

I also did not find scroll function but for

> It works, but is not efficient, because there is a chance that when I SwipeUP() the cell I want to Tap won't be visible, for Swiping to much, and can't Tap at the cell.

you may want to validate cell on some attribute (like label or title) before tapping on it to avoid incorrect tap.

Comment: Yes, is a good idea to make a validation of the cell, but this doesn't solve my problem, anyways at this point I'm using the swipeUp function.